# Winrar error: Attempting to correct the invalid file or folder name

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows, filenames, compression

Posting this since I could not find it using Google and this took weeks.

When extracting using Winrar, I am getting

```
! Attempting to correct the invalid file or folder name
! Renaming C:\Users\noam.s\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DRa30340.29792\756417188\uvrabbit\aux.py to C:\Users\noam.s\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DRa30340.29792\756417188\uvrabbit\_aux.py
```

[image]

What may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

[Some file names are forbidden in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794287/cannot-write-to-any-path-with-filename-aux#:%7E:text=AUX%20is%20reserved%20name%20for,LPT7%2C%20LPT8%2C%20and%20LPT9).

In this case, one of the compressed files was named `aux`. The compression was done in Linux, so it succeeded, but couldn't be uncompressed in Windows.

It is good to know what this error means, since you can understand why automatic uncompression fails in some cases due to this.

[See here what this could cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886164/pycharm-doesnt-recognize-packages-with-remote-interpreter).

I hope this saves someone some time.